# Cant save image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to save images from a video file but It couldn't save any image in my hard drive. I compiled following program without errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int c=1;
    IplImage* img=0;
    IplImage* small;
    IplImage* small=new IplImage(inputArray);
    char buffer[1000];
    CvCapture* cv_cap=cvCaptureFromFile("test.avi");
    cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(1) {

        img=cvQueryFrame(cv_cap);
        cvShowImage("Video",img);
        small = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width/2,img->height/2), 8, 3);
        sprintf(buffer,"C:/image%u.jpg",c);


        c++;
        if (cvWaitKey(100)== 27) break;
    }

    cvDestroyWindow("Video");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a 2.3.1 openCV library and Visual Studio 2010.
How can I save the image from a video file?

---

I have also tried this code,above program code are something wrong.please see following program code.After i adding following code ,also there was a same problem.

```
   cvSaveImage(buffer,img);
```

Corrected program is shown below.please see this and tell me what i did wrong.but there is not compile error.after i run the program it doesn't save any image.

```
  #include"stdafx.h"
  #include<cv.h>
  #include<highgui.h>
  #include<cxcore.h>


  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int c=1;
  IplImage* img=0;
  char buffer[1000];
  CvCapture* cv_cap=cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
  cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  while(1) {

  img=cvQueryFrame(cv_cap);
  cvShowImage("Video",img);
  sprintf(buffer,"D:/image%u.jpg",c);
  cvSaveImage(buffer,img);
  c++;
    if (cvWaitKey(100)== 27) break;
  }

  cvDestroyWindow("Video");
  return 0;
  }
```

can you tell me how to save a image .above program doesn't save any images.please give me your suggestions.thank you.

Comment: where in this code are you trying to save it? looks like youre not doing anything with `buffer` which contains the filename.

Comment: Also, why use the old C interface if you're using C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [doesn't save any image.. when saving frames of a video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966600/doesnt-save-any-image-when-saving-frames-of-a-video)

Comment: @NimPointer Atleast mark the correct answer , and don't put the answer in your question

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually save the image:

```
cvSaveImage(buffer ,img);
```

Also, the following is redundant:

```
IplImage* small; // <-- you don't need this
IplImage* small=new IplImage(inputArray);
```

Comment: i am new to openCV,i also add above code..but still have a same problem.please see my corrected program below...Thank you for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved the problem or not. if not you can use imwrite("test.jpg",img); to save an image,

here is an example-
    while(1) {

```
  img=cvQueryFrame(cv_cap);
  cvShowImage("Video",img);
  imwrite("test.jpg",img);
}
```