# doesn't save any image.. when saving frames of a video

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cant save image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962738/cant-save-image-using-opencv)

I have tried following code,please see this and tell me what did i wrong.but there is not compile error.after i run the program it doesn't save any image.

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<cxcore.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

int c=1;
IplImage* img=0;
char buffer[1000];
CvCapture* cv_cap=cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
cvNamedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while(1) {

img=cvQueryFrame(cv_cap);
cvShowImage("Video",img);
sprintf(buffer,"D:/image%u.jpg",c);
cvSaveImage(buffer,img);
c++;
  if (cvWaitKey(100)== 27) break;
}

cvDestroyWindow("Video"); 
return 0;
}
```

can you tell me how to save a image .above program doesn't save any images.please give me your suggestions.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
IplImage *destination = cvCreateImage(cvSize( img->width, img->height ), IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvCvtColor( img, destination, CV_RGB2GRAY );
cvSaveImage( "C:/Users/SP/Desktop/sample.jpg", destination );
```

It converts to grey image; use it as desired.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a permissions problem, only admin can write to the top level folder

Try making a sub-directory and writing to eg `sprintf(buffer,"D:/data/image%u.jpg",c);`

Answer (score 0):

I'll say this for the 100th time in these OpenCV posts: **code safely** by checking the return of the calls. `cvSaveImage()` returns 0 when it fails to save the image:

```
if (!(cvSaveImage(buffer,img))
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed to save image" << std::endl;
}
```

If you see the error message being displayed, you should check if the destination directory exists and if your user has the authorization to create files inside it.

Comment: It works..i thank all of you for gave me your suggestions.Thank you very much.